# how to stop rebuild non provided value widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I tried to mimic the first sample app using provider, but when I logged to see if it was rebuilding for each widget, the Button Widget and CounterText Widget were rebuilding.

The only one I want to rebuild is CounterText.
How can this be prevented?

```dart
class Counter with ChangeNotifier {
  var count = 0;

  void incrementCounter() {
    count++;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<Counter>(create: (context) => Counter())
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("test"),
        ),
        body: Column(children: [CounterText(), const StateText(), const Button()]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CounterText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("built counter text");
    final provider = Provider.of<Counter>(context);

    return Text(provider.count.toString());
  }
}

class StateText extends StatelessWidget {
  const StateText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("built state text");

    return Text("stateText");
  }
}

class Button extends StatelessWidget {
  const Button({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("built button");
    final provider = Provider.of<Counter>(context);
    return FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
      provider.incrementCounter();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It rebuild the `Button` widget because you are listening for change. To avoid that, you must access your `ChangeNotifier` like this

```
final provider = Provider.of<Counter>(context, listen: false);
```

That way you are not rebuilding the widget when the `ChangeNotifier` value is updated